# `pip install cudf-cuda100` results in "ERROR: No matching distribution found for cudf-cuda100"

Tags: python, anaconda, rapids, cudf

I run Windows 10 and have installed Anaconda. I am trying to install `cudf` but I repeatedly fail:

```
(tf2) C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install cudf-cuda100
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cudf-cuda100 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for cudf-cuda100


(tf2) C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda install -c nvidia/label/cuda10.0 -c rapidsai/label/cuda10.0 -c numba -c conda-forge -c defaults cudf
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - cudf

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/nvidia/label/cuda10.0/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/nvidia/label/cuda10.0/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/rapidsai/label/cuda10.0/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/rapidsai/label/cuda10.0/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/numba/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/numba/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

My CUDA version:

```
(tf2) C:\WINDOWS\system32>nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2018 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sat_Aug_25_21:08:04_Central_Daylight_Time_2018
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.0, V10.0.130
```

What would you advise me to do?

Answer (score 1):

RAPIDS doesn't have Windows support and this won't work today. We're exploring ways to provide Windows support, but currently, this is not on our roadmap as a feature in the near future.